# Using Current row calculations within variable set (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio v17.5.

I am trying to use values from the selected table to run a calculation. For example below. I want the Start value to be the current rows Final Inventory Number minus the Stocking Total Number. So for each row this would be satisfied with the specific values contained in that row for that table. Is there a way to achieve this with set variables?

```
USE [Fishery_Tanks_Ponds]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Report_WhiteSturgeon]
AS
    DECLARE @Start_Inv NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @Start_Inv = Final_Inventory_# - Stocking_Total_#

    SELECT
        @Start_Inv AS [Start Inventory],
        Stocking_Total_#, Final_Inventory_# 
    FROM
        aa_Tanks_Ponds
```

The end result should look something like:

```
Start Inventory  |  Stocking_Total_#   |   Final_Inventory_#
300              |  500                |   800
400              |  250                |   650
800              |  350                |   1150
```

Comment: I think you are looking for a query like this: `select [Final_Inventory_#] - [Stocking_Total_#] as [Start Inventory],[Stocking_Total_#],[Final_Inventory_#] from aa_Tanks_Ponds`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for the information!  I'm always looking to improve efficiency and best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with the variable, but can't you simply perform the calculation in the query like

```
select [Final_Inventory_#] - [Stocking_Total_#] as [Start Inventory],
       Stocking_Total_#,
       Final_Inventory_# 
from   aa_Tanks_Ponds
```

if your calculation is too complex, you can consider using CROSS APPLY and perform the calculation inside

```
select [Start Inventory],
       Stocking_Total_#,
       Final_Inventory_# 
from   aa_Tanks_Ponds 
       cross apply
       (
           select [Final_Inventory_#] - [Stocking_Total_#] as [Start Inventory]
       ) si
```

OR

provided that the calculation is not too complex or dependent on other external table, you can do it in table creation using computed column also.

Comment: I just wanted to keep the select clean.  This example I only included two in the calculation but I will be adding about 7 expressions.  Yours executes perfectly though.

Comment: if you want, you can create a view to do that

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Much appreciated.